# How can I make my dash work with microtype?

Tags: punctuation, microtype, protrusion

Consider the following definition:

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}

\def\Dash{\unskip\thinspace\textemdash\thinspace\ignorespaces\allowbreak}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum doler sit amet. Here is some text that I don't know what
I'm typing but it's okay \Dash all I need is enough text for the line
break and then I can put in my custom dash at it \Dash because
\emph{I'm so clever}.  (This worked out surprisingly well.)
\end{document}
```

How can I define `\Dash` to properly protrude into the margin,
  as the hyphen character does?

[image: output]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The definition of `\thinspace` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 1315:
\def\thinspace{\kern .16667em }
```

so it's a kern; since it's not followed by glue it's not a feasible line break point.

You probably want `\hspace{.16667em}` instead of it; then `\allowbreak` is not needed. On the other hand, `\ignorespaces` does nothing at all where you place it, because its only action is to trigger expansion of `\allowbreak`. Spaces are ignored after `\Dash` anyway.

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand\Dash{\unskip\thinspace\textemdash\hspace{.16667em}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum doler sit amet. Here is some text that I don't know what
I'm typing but it's okay \Dash all I need is enough text for the line
break and then I can put in my custom dash at it \Dash because
\emph{I'm so clever}.  (This worked out surprisingly well.)
\end{document}
```

[image]