# Em dash out of right margin

Tags: margins, hyphenation, microtype

I am almost sure this question was already asked somewhere (I couldn't find it). Still why my em dash and the word proceeding it are typeset out of margins?

[image]

the source is

```
proliferation---nextword
```

Has it something to do with the hyphenation of the word *proliferation*?

I am using the package `microtype` if it matters and I tried what suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56658/27466) (although the problem is slightly different).

Comment: I belive that this is a "feature" of the `microtype` package.

Comment: was it this one: [How can I make my dash work with microtype?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163116)

Comment: @cmhughes Mmm, maybe But then according to the answer I need to define a new command `\Dash` while I am not using any command but `---`. Any way around?

Comment: Without seeing the complete paragraph it's next to impossible to diagnose, let alone remedy, the situation. The result you currently have, as unattractive as it is, is probably the least-bad solution for the paragraph. Do you have some very long and/or unbreakable words elsewhere in the paragraph? Please consider posting an MWE rather than a screenshot.

Comment: Would you rather have the words spread apart or scrunched together?  In either case, you can always adjust the glue.

Comment: I would prefer to have the em dash going to a new line...

Comment: @Francesco -- looking at the bit out output you show, even if the em dash goes to a new line, the line ending with "proliferation" will be overfull, so it would probably be better to allow hyphenation within that word.  the question cited by cmhughes gives the appropriate method for that.  and no, there really isn't any other practical way than defining a new command.